# adding zeros to the lpad

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query which I convert it to decimal and I want to have it with zeros in the left pad it is not giving me an output when I run this query:

```
SELECT  LPAD(TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'9999999999999999999999D99'),12,'0') Transaction_Amount  
FROM ln01mast WHERE acno=214
```

Comment: The LPAD with a length argument of 12 means that only the portion that fits within 12 characters will be returned. It's not clear what you actually want returned; we'd really examples of the decimal values, and exactly the character string you want returned (e.g. when the decimal value is 16 digits, is negative, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'000000000000D00') Transaction_Amount  
  FROM ln01mast 
 WHERE acno = 214
```

Sample output:

```
| TRANSACTION_AMOUNT |
|--------------------|
|    000000002987.87 |
```

*Note: adjust the number of leading zeros as needed*

or (based on your comments)

```
SELECT '000000000000' || TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'FM99999999999999D99') Transaction_Amount  
  FROM ln01mast 
 WHERE acno = 214
```

Sample output:

```
|  TRANSACTION_AMOUNT |
|---------------------|
| 0000000000002987.87 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bcbb/5)** demo

Comment: ya but I want it to be all zeros from the left side (dynamic)

Comment: I want 12 zeros to be added next to the number regarless what the number is

Comment: It is showing the zeros al the left but the digits of the decimals are not showing it showing as 0000000000001538595.

Comment: I got it right now I just converted 'FM99999999999999D99' to 'FM99999999999999D00'

Comment: Is there a way to make the zeros dynamic ex: the total number should be 12 digits (000000555555.00)

Comment: @user2786306 That's what my the very example was all about. See it again. For that you only need just `TO_CHAR()`.